# list capture device in list or menu

Tags: c++, directshow, win32com

I could not understand how to use a menu or list to allow user to select its appropiate device.
There is something missing. I don't get it. Can you enlight my mind please?

```
void    fillDevices(HWND list)
{

IPropertyBag *tmpBag=NULL;
    tmpMonk->BindToStorage(0,0,IID_IPropertyBag,(void **)&tmpBag);
    VariantInit(&varName);
    //DevicePath-Description-FriendlyName
    checkIt(tmpBag->Read(L"FriendlyName",&varName,0));

// i need to fill it  with device names and be able to chose from the list 

    VariantClear(&varName);
    tmpBag->Release();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows SDK [AMCap sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does exactly this:

```
// put all installed video and audio devices in the menus
//
void AddDevicesToMenu()
{
// ...
    while(hr = pEm->Next(1, &pM, &cFetched), hr==S_OK)
    {
        IPropertyBag *pBag=0;

        hr = pM->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void **)&pBag);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            VARIANT var;
            var.vt = VT_BSTR;
            hr = pBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &var, NULL);
            if(hr == NOERROR)
            {
                AppendMenu(hMenuSub, MF_STRING, MENU_VDEVICE0 + uIndex,
                    var.bstrVal);
//...
```

Relative path in Windows SDK: \Samples\multimedia\directshow\capture\amcap